# Can't play music using Banshee on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux

When running Banshee from the terminal, after I click on a song, a little x appears next the song title and I get this output:

```
GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_query: assertion `GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed
```

As Banshee starts, I also get this output (it may not be related, I have no idea):

```
[Warn  17:57:43.999] Failed to start DAAP client - System.Exception: No Zeroconf providers could be found or initialized. Necessary daemon may not be running. (in `Mono.Zeroconf')
```

I've tried updating gstreamer, but that didn't help. I'm currently using Gnome3. Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Try testing other gstreamer-based media player (i.e. Totem, Rhythmbox), and if they don't work either (for the same files you tried to play with Banshee) then you have a broken GStreamer installation.